# How to make custom navigationbar like below in Android app using Android Studio and java

Tags: java, android

How to make custom navigationbar like below  in Android app using Android Studio and java
Please help me i am using custom actionbar not toolbar at all

[image]

Comment: do you still need help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We would love to help you, but there are some problems in the current format/content of your question that makes it hard for some of us to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to create your own drawer navigation, you should have good experience in android.

If you want some thing like in your photo [this library may help](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)
You can add this drawer to your project by adding these dependencies in you app gradle and

```
implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:${lastestMaterialDrawerRelease}"

//required support lib modules
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${versions.appcompat}"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:${versions.recyclerView}"
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:${versions.annotation}"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:${versions.material}"
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:${versions.constraintLayout}"

// Add for NavController support
implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer-nav:${lastestMaterialDrawerRelease}"
```

adding this to your activity

```java
DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this).build()
```

For more customisation read [docs](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer#add-items-and-adding-some-functionality)